# Python Pandas read_html fails when reading tables from Wikipedia

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, wikipedia

I am trying to read the tables from a Wikipedia page using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013–14_Premier_League')
```

Doing that generates the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in    position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried

```
pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013–14_Premier_League', encoding='utf-8')
```

But still get the same error. The following works:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017–18_Premier_League')
c = r.content
dfs = pd.read_html(c)
```

What I want to know is how to get `pd.read_html()` to work directly on the url without `requests`. What is it that I don't understand about encoding or is this a problem with Pandas?

I am running an Anaconda distribution of Pandas 0.21.1 and Python 3.5.4. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Raised an issue on the Pandas repo (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21499).

Answer (score -2):

The issue is with the

> https

Try to remove the S at the https, and you may want to refer to the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_html.html#)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as Wikipedia redirects the request to `https`

Comment: That might be a further issue; it doesn't seem a likely cause for this specific error.